# How can I solve the "Read Request Limit Error"?

Tags: google-sheets

I receive this error while trying to export form my datagrid to Google Sheets. How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't make many requests too quickly.

You are either exceeding your quota or you are making too many requests too quickly.

Also, look into batch requests

> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate

As you may be trying to make a call to the API for every single cell updated, which is an easy way to run into the above error.

If you must do it on a cell by cell basis, you would have to insert a small delay between requests. Bear in mind that although the [usage page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) says:

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.

This does not mean that you can make 100 requests in 1 second and then wait 99 seconds. This will give you a quota error like what you are running into. You would have to put in a one second delay between requests, for example.